# Auto Launching PHP-FPM

Tags: macos, launchctl

My plist file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd" >
<plist version='1.0'>
<dict>
<key>Label</key><string>org.macports.php-fpm</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/opt/local/bin/daemondo</string>
    <string>--label=php-fpm</string>
    <string>--start-cmd</string>
    <string>/opt/local/sbin/php-fpm</string>
    <string>;</string>
    <string>--pid=fileauto</string>
    <string>--pidfile</string>
    <string>/opt/local/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid</string>
</array>
<key>Debug</key><false/>
<key>Disabled</key><true/>
<key>OnDemand</key><false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After rebooting, it's not loading up automatically. I still have to manually start php-fpm. I have tried unloading and adding RunAtLoad etc. with no luck and tried both these launchctl commands.

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.php-fpm.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.php-fpm.plist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `<key>Disabled</key><true/>` AND adding `<key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I was using the Nginx plist file generated by macports as a template for this one and oddly enough nginx starts up on it's own even with the disabled key set as true.

Comment: nginx' plist is probably activated with `launchctl load -w ...`, which'll permanently override the Disabled key -- but that's an unnecessarily complex and fragile way to do things.